# GAE MemCache behaviour of put() + ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached

The `put(...)` method of GAE's memcahe API accepts as an argument (in one of it's overloaded implementations) a `SetPolicy` argument. In the Javadocs [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService.SetPolicy.html#ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT) it sais that if you chose "ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT" as policy it's, and I quote:

"useful to avoid race conditions."

My questions are:

1. what happends with an expired value that was set with the same key? If I add to memcache something like (key=1, value=whatever), then this entry expires, and then I try to add (key=1, value=whatever2) using ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT is whatever2 added to cache or not?
2. What does it mean "useful for race conditions"? More specifically, does it mean that if I use `put(...)` with `ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT` SetPolicy I am no longer required to use [getIdentifiable](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService.html#getIdentifiable(java.lang.Object)) and [putIfUntouched](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/memcache/MemcacheService.html#putIfUntouched%28java.lang.Object,%20com.google.appengine.api.memcache.MemcacheService.IdentifiableValue,%20java.lang.Object,%20com.google.appengine.api.memcache.Expiration%29) in order to avoid race conditions when adding stuff concurrentlly to the memcache?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If the value expires, it's not in memcache anymore, so the RPC will set it.
2. If you do a get, then do a put only if nothing was there, you've introduced a race condition whereby someone else might've put the data while you were checking. Doing a single operation avoids this.

Comment: Thanx, that's a very clear answer. However I find it a bit tedious to use putIfUntouched and getIdentifiable, as this means I have to locally (to my current app instance) store all the last objects I retrieved for a certain key, in order to use them with the putIfUntouched method...