# Corrupted value in GAE Memcache

Tags: java, google-app-engine, memcached

Sometimes (when I perform stress test) the object stored in memcache is corrupted (it lacks a property and when I try to access it gives me "NullPointerException"). 
Could it be related to wrong synchronization between different memcache writes? In fact in different part of my code I just update the UserAccount stored in Memcache in this way:

```
cache.put(tempUser.getKey(), tempUser);
```

.. and I try to retrieve in this way:

```
if (cache.contains(key)) {
    readObject = (T) cache.get(key);
    return readObject;
}
```

Related to this retrieving I get NullPointerException, when I try (for exampple) to retrieve:

```
readObject.getMyProperty()
```

I tried to understand this feature (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview#Safely_Handling_Concurrent_Memcache_Updates), but it doens't seem very well documented.
I also had a look to these answers on stackoverflow:

- [GAE MemCache behaviour of put() + ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8080933/gae-memcache-behaviour-of-put-add-only-if-not-present)
- [Safely Handling Concurrent Memcache Updates in AppEngine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501852/safely-handling-concurrent-memcache-updates-in-appengine)

.. but it doesn't seem realated to my needs.
At the end I just need to be sure a value is well stored in the cache, without the risk of race condition could affect its integrity.

================================================================================
UPDATE:
I try to specify better the behaviour: I get "NullPointerException" in this row:

```
if(readObject!=null && readObject.getMyProperty.equals("test"))
```

so that it is not (only) totally null, but just a property. It seems really to be corrupted. Apart from that I know I have to improve the retrieve phase!

================================================================================

NEW UPDATE: I found the object in memcache with all the properties equals to null, apart from the key one

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Between the call to cache.contains() and cache.get() your entry may get evicted from memcache. A solution would be to just call cache.get() and check for a null result in which case the entry isn't there anymore. You even save some milliseconds for the unneeded call. Never rely on an unchanged state between calls. Instead memcache gives you helpful atomic compound operations to avoid race condition like increment(), putIfUntouched() and put()+ADD_ONLY_IF_NOT_PRESENT.

Comment: thank you for you answer, for sure I have to better implement the retry phase, but the strange thing is that the object is not "totally" null: it just doesn't have a property.

Comment: I don't know of a good documentation but it works like this: fetch the memchache value using getIdentifiable() instead of get(). That returns a wrapper object where the real value can be obtained by calling .getValue(). When updating the same key with putIfUntouched() you must provide the old wrapper object as it contains the versioning information. It's just a straightforward implementation of optimistic locking.

Comment: yes ok thank you. This is clear, but if the putIfUntouched returns false? What I have to do? Delete the value in cache and put the new one? This is not atomic anymore ..

Comment: can you please answer if you have experience on that? I need to have the latest value in memcache. If putIfUntouched returns false, what is an atomic way to put the latest object there?

Answer (score 1):

Memcache uses standard Java serialization to serialize/deserialize objects.

To make this work your classes (and all fields in them) must implement `java.io.Serializable`.

What type is your `MyProperty` field?

Comment: It implements an interface that "extends Serializable, InstanceCallbacks". So it's already compliant with what you said .. :( The key point in my opinion is here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/memcache/overview#Safely_Handling_Concurrent_Memcache_Updates .. but I cannot understand how it works in use cases different from the one with increment a value

Comment: Is there any chance the class implementing the Serializable interface is not coming from your java source code directly but is created on the fly? In that case the serialized objects may not be completely compatible between different GAE instances. That SHOULD result in InvalidClassException in most cases but if serialVersionUID is set to a fixed value the result COULD be a garbled object. The effect should only be seen if more than one GAE instance is active or after restart of the application as memcache values will still be there.